# How to set proper permissions for Magento on server?

Tags: magento-1.8, server-setup, permissions

I'm getting lot of issues with permissions.

In magento admin panel:

> Your web server is configured incorrectly. As a result, configuration files with sensitive information are accessible from the outside. Please contact your hosting provider.

When I upload images from cms:

> The directory is not writable by server.

If anyone access this url: http://example.com/app/etc/modules/

they can see easily configuration settings.

Using FTP account: I'm not able to override any file and some times I'm not able copy any local folder to server through FTP.

My application place is `/var/www/html`.

with senior developer advice I execute following commands:

```
find <foldername> -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
find <foldername> -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

and below are present permissions for each folder.

```
drwxr-xr-x 12 root     root     4096 Jun 10 13:06 var
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root     4096 Jun 10 13:06 www
drwxr-xr-x 15 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 18 07:29 html

root@web-server-magento:/var/www/html# ls -l

total 14644
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data     2834 Nov 26  2013 api.php
drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data www-data     4096 Jun 17 11:16 app
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data     2831 Nov 26  2013 cron.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data      717 Nov 26  2013 cron.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data  2454234 Oct 26  2011 data.sql
drwxr-xr-x  8 www-data www-data     4096 Jun 11 07:21 downloader
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data     4096 Nov 26  2013 errors
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data     1150 Nov 26  2013 favicon.ico
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data     5979 Nov 26  2013 get.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data     4096 Nov 26  2013 includes
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    11510 Jun 10 13:06 index1.html
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data     2642 Nov 26  2013 index.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data     2366 Nov 26  2013 index.php.sample
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data     6441 Nov 26  2013 install.php
drwxr-xr-x 12 www-data www-data     4096 Jun 18 06:28 js
drwxr-xr-x 13 www-data www-data     4096 Nov 26  2013 lib
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    10421 Nov 26  2013 LICENSE_AFL.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    10679 Nov 26  2013 LICENSE.html
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    10410 Nov 26  2013 LICENSE.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    10327 Jun 11 14:48 logo.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data     1319 Nov 26  2013 mage
drwxr-xr-x 13 www-data www-data     4096 Jun 18 07:29 media
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data      886 Nov 26  2013 php.ini.sample
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data     4096 Nov 26  2013 pkginfo
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data   585086 Nov 26  2013 RELEASE_NOTES.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data     4096 Nov 26  2013 shell
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data     4096 Nov 26  2013 skin
drwxr-xr-x  9 www-data www-data     4096 Jun 18 06:57 var
```

Please comment if any extra information needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I tried magento cleanup.still same problem.I think problem with apache configuration or htacces file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please check and verify below steps:

1. Check if your server is compatible with Magento. Download file from this link [Magento Server Compatibility check](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento) and follow the instructions given.
2. Check for the `.htaccess` in each folder and in root too. Magento has `.htaccess` in almost all folders. Verify it for media folder in case the problem is with image
3. Execute the following server commands going into your project folder:

   ```
   find ./ -type f | xargs chmod 644
   find ./ -type d | xargs chmod 755
   ```

   This gives 644 permission to files and 755 to folders.
4. Next give 777 permission to var and media folder if the problem still persists, use the following commands for it:

   ```
   chmod -Rf 777 var
   chmod -Rf 777 media
   ```
5. Also check the html folder permission of your server. It should be 755.

Hope this should resolve your problem.

Comment: A note about .htaccess files. These are only required if Apache web server is used. .htaccess files in each folders are bad for Apache performance because it has to check these for each folder.

For more information see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

In the beginning there's a warning: You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file.

Comment: Thanks for that... but i have noticed its present in almost every main folder of Magento...

Comment: _Only required for apache_ => which means you need to take appropriate steps to off-limit these folders by whatever means the other flavors of web server use. The .htaccess files all are there to protect the contents or even more importantly, prevent script execution out of folders that have global RWX. Most people using Apache don't have access to the http server config so it's kind of a red herring to mention removing something needed to secure the file access without properly acknowledging why they're there. Also important is giving alternatives to properly replacing that security model.

Comment: getting `Operation not permitted` on all files when running `find ./ -type f | xargs chmod 644` . Tried  with `sudo` as well.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with your server permission

Answer (score 4):

Please check if your FTP and SSH user are in the www-data group.

Your files and folders belong to the www-data user and group:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data     2642 Nov 26  2013 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 13 www-data www-data     4096 Jun 18 07:29 media
```

Your FTP error message (I'm not able to override any file) makes me believe your FTP user is not in the www-data group.

From the command line, run and check which groups your ftp and ssh user belong to:

```
$ groups [username]
```

If there's no www-data listed, adjust the settings with your server-admin.

Answer (score 4):

At your discretion, you should either assign all web server files to the www-data user and group, or just the group. It is often convenient, and still secure, to make the owner of the files yourself so you can more easily edit them, especially if you wanted to manage such files via a repo.

If you decided to make all web server files owned and group-owned by www-data, I recommend the following permissions:

```
find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

find /var/www/html/var -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
find /var/www/html/var -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

find /var/www/html/media -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
find /var/www/html/media -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

If you want to have the files owned by another user that should be able to edit everything, you can do 775 and 664 instead. Whatever you do, **never set anything to 777**. You rarely, if ever, have any reason to do that. In this case, you know who should and shouldn't access the files, and with what permission level, so you can explicitly set what you need, rather than let any and everyone read/write/execute everything.

Finally, and this is the most important step, you will want to make the /app directory and contents inaccessible for serving by allowing the `.htaccess` files to regulate access. Simply add something like the following, if using httpd:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
  AllowOverride FileInfo Indexes Options Limit
</Directory>
```

Comment: I also just found their [ownership settings guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html#install-privs).

Answer (score 3):

I have used the magento cleanup code for resetting the permissions, it has worked for me.
Can you please try using the cleanup code as below :-

```
<?php

## Function to set file permissions to 0644 and folder permissions to 0755

function AllDirChmod( $dir = "./", $dirModes = 0755, $fileModes = 0644 ){
   $d = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $dir );
   foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $d, 1 ) as $path ){
      if( $path->isDir() ) chmod( $path, $dirModes );
      else if( is_file( $path ) ) chmod( $path, $fileModes );
  }
}

## Function to clean out the contents of specified directory

function cleandir($dir) {

    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && is_file($dir.'/'.$file)) {
                if (unlink($dir.'/'.$file)) { }
                else { echo $dir . '/' . $file . ' (file) NOT deleted!<br />'; }
            }
            else if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)) {
                cleandir($dir.'/'.$file);
                if (rmdir($dir.'/'.$file)) { }
                else { echo $dir . '/' . $file . ' (directory) NOT deleted!<br />'; }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }

}

function isDirEmpty($dir){
     return (($files = @scandir($dir)) && count($files) <= 2);
}

echo "----------------------- CLEANUP START -------------------------<br/>";
$start = (float) array_sum(explode(' ',microtime()));
echo "<br/>*************** SETTING PERMISSIONS ***************<br/>";
echo "Setting all folder permissions to 755<br/>";
echo "Setting all file permissions to 644<br/>";
AllDirChmod( "." );
echo "Setting pear permissions to 550<br/>";
chmod("pear", 550);

echo "<br/>****************** CLEARING CACHE ******************<br/>";

if (file_exists("var/cache")) {
    echo "Clearing var/cache<br/>";
    cleandir("var/cache");
}

if (file_exists("var/session")) {
    echo "Clearing var/session<br/>";
    cleandir("var/session");
}

if (file_exists("var/minifycache")) {
    echo "Clearing var/minifycache<br/>";
    cleandir("var/minifycache");
}

if (file_exists("downloader/pearlib/cache")) {
    echo "Clearing downloader/pearlib/cache<br/>";
    cleandir("downloader/pearlib/cache");
}

if (file_exists("downloader/pearlib/download")) {
    echo "Clearing downloader/pearlib/download<br/>";
    cleandir("downloader/pearlib/download");
}

if (file_exists("downloader/pearlib/pear.ini")) {
    echo "Removing downloader/pearlib/pear.ini<br/>";
    unlink ("downloader/pearlib/pear.ini");
}

echo "<br/>************** CHECKING FOR EXTENSIONS ***********<br/>";
If (!isDirEmpty("app/code/local/")) { 
    echo "-= WARNING =- Overrides or extensions exist in the app/code/local folder<br/>";
}
If (!isDirEmpty("app/code/community/")) { 
    echo "-= WARNING =- Overrides or extensions exist in the app/code/community folder<br/>";
}
$end = (float) array_sum(explode(' ',microtime()));
echo "<br/>------------------- CLEANUP COMPLETED in:". sprintf("%.4f", ($end-$start))." seconds ------------------<br/>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this link to check the permissions for your Magento installation

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_filesystem_permissions
```

You can download [Magento clean up tool](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions) , and run it on your server.

also lastly check the group/owner of your files on server, and the ftp user you are using has sufficient update/delete rights.

Comment: The link is dead now.

Answer (score 1):

set `app/etc/config.xml` and `app/etc/local.xml` files to 644

make sure that you have all `.htaccess` files exist in magento's default locations, like you will have that file at `root`, `app` folder etc

Answer (score 1):

MAGENTO 2 Centos 7 Server

See https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2882#issuecomment-217661873

> To fix the message
>
> > Your web server is set up incorrectly and allows unauthorized access to sensitive files. Please contact your hosting provider
>
> 1. SSH - Run the following command from your root account.
>
>    ```
>    chown -R accountuser:accountusergroup /path-to-root-folderl/
>    ```
> 2. SSH - Run the following command from the domain account user(not your web server account such as apache etc).
>
>    ```
>    find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; & find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento
>
>    chmod -R g+w /path-to-root-folderl/{pub,var}
>    chmod -R g+w /path-to-root-folderl/{app/etc,vendor}
>    chmod -R g+s pub/static pub/media .
>    find var/generation -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
>    find var/session -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
>    ```
> 3. SSH - Run the following command from your root account.
>
>    ```
>    chown -R domain_account_user:webservergroup /path-to-root-folderl/var
>    chown -R domain_account_user:webservergroup /path-to-root-folder/app/etc
>    chown -R domain_account_user:webservergroup /path-to-root-folderl/pub
>    chown -R webserverUSER:webservergroup /path-to-root-folder/var/session
>    ```
>
> This will fix this error and many other error. Note: disable SUPHP when using magento 2, you will save yourself a lot of headache.
>   Currently I'm running mod_mpm_event with ea-apache24-mod_cgid and PHP 7 and ea-php70-php-fpm.
>
> I had my magento 2 running with just mod_mpm_event with ea-apache24-mod_cgid and PHP 7 before I added PHP-FPM.
>
> If you are running cpanel/ apache and you don't want to use easyapache to move to mod_mpm_event + ea-apache24-mod_cgid you can use shell from ssh .
>   Run the command bellow from ssh .
>   yum shell
>   remove ea-apache24-mod_mpm_worker
>   remove ea-apache24-mod_cgi
>   install ea-apache24-mod_mpm_event
>   install ea-apache24-mod_cgid
>   run
>   quit

Comment: Your answer applies to Magento 2? This question is about Magento 1...

Comment: Where in the question do you see Magento 1 or Magento 2 ? I found this page looking for magento 2. That is why I clearly say MAGENTO 2 Centos 7 Server to make it clear.

Comment: The question itself is clearly tagged "magento-1.8", also the file structure show in the question is clearly Magento 1. Please feel free to [Ask this Question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) again yourself for Magento2 and answer it yourself with the answer you have posted here.