# Error while uploading site from local to live server

Tags: magento-1.9, websites, localhost, theme-fallback

I have uploaded the quick-start package of theme `sm-g3shop` in my localhost , it was working fine showing exactly the demo website but when i have uploaded that website on  live server from localhost it show only html type of data. All the elements of theme are disrupted and its not showing as expected.
please help me to solve this error

[image]

[image]

Comment: in your screenshot i understand JS and css are not loaded. check view source all css are loading properly also clear cache and check it

Comment: Confirm you permissions are correct, confirm you have CSS/JS merge turned off before you backup and restore. / Confirm all your files are there

Comment: @RamaChandran how should i do that ?

Comment: What is the os you are using? @prince added the ans :)

Comment: check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24373/how-to-set-proper-permissions-for-magento-on-server?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

1) Are you sure that you have copied all files ? `app/design`, `skin` and `media` ? check these please.

2) Check also if you have set your current theme and package in :

- `system->configuration->design->package`: put your **package**.
- `system->configuration->design->themes->Default`: put your **theme**.
- the other fields you leave them empty.

3) check the premission of folders :

- `app/design` = 755,  `skin` = 755, `media` = 755

**Edit**

You can check this with:

```
FTP : right click on folder->Right to access files (the last one)

SSH : chmod -R 755 media
```

4) Clear your Magento and Browser cache.

Comment: Please tell me how should i check the permission of folders.

Comment: look my update please